# jQuery/AJAX - Load content into a div when button clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Would someone be able to help here?

I would like to fill a div e.g.

```
<div id="contenthere"></div>
```

with content from an external file e.g.

```
/includes/about-info.html
```

when a button with a certain class is clicked e.g.

```
<p class="classloader">Click Here</p>
```

Does anyone have a quick code example they can show me to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`jQuery.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.classloader.').click(function(){
        $('#contenthere').load('/includes/about-info.html');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Load latest version of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
  $(".classloader").click(function(){
    $("#contenthere").load("/includes/about-info.html");
  });
});
</script>
```

**HTML code:**

```
<p class="classloader">Click Here</p>
<div id="contenthere"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subscribe to the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event of the paragraph and then use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to send an AJAX request to the given url and inject the results into the specified selector:

```
$(function() {
    $('.classloader').click(function() {
        $('#contenthere').load('/includes/about-info.html');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var myurl = 'myfileonthesamedomain.html';

$('button').click(function(){
    $('div.loadme').load(myurl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple and sobher it also do run time binding as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.classloader',(function(){
        $('#contenthere').load('/includes/about-info.html');
    });
})
```